# Javascript generated link does not display in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a bilingual site with each language version stored in a separate directory. I then use the javascript below to generate a link that will look for the language directory in the URL and replace it with the other directory to switch between languages.

```
(function () {
  // this assumes you're on the en version and want to switch to chi
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  var url = window.location.href.replace('/eng/', '/chi/');
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  link.innerText = '中文'; // or whatever the link should be
  link.href = url;
  holder.appendChild(link);
  document.write(holder.innerHTML);
})();
```

It works fine in Chrome and IE, but Firefox is not displaying the link at all. Please help!

Comment: can you print helder.innerhtml and see what is it generating on different browsers?

Comment: `innerText` is not a standard property. Try creating a text node inside the `<a>` element instead. And if I may ask, why not use jQuery -- which would make things like this *A LOT* easier?

Comment: Using `document.write` can be a horrible practice. You seems to only need the `<a>` tag, which can be done by `document.body.appendChild(link)`. Try to use DOM.

Comment: It would be much easier to have both links in the HTML and just toggle their visibility.

Comment: What @AtesGoral said, or use `link.textContent = '中文'`.

Answer (score 0):

thx @AtesGoral and @katspaugh! Revised to below and works now

```
(function () {
  // this assumes you're on the en version and want to switch to chi
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  var url = window.location.href.replace('/eng/', '/chi/');
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  link.textContent = '中文'; // or whatever the link should be
  link.href = url;
  holder.appendChild(link);
  document.write(holder.innerHTML);
})();
```